@types/fs-extra: error TS2694: Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'EncodingOption'
All,
I have this following error while trying to build project in aws
node_modules/@types/fs-extra/index.d.ts(917,48): error TS2694: Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'EncodingOption'.

environment :
Dedendency: "fs-extra": "10.1.0",
Devdependency: @types/fs-extra: "^11.0.4",
typescript : "5.3.3",
node.js: 20.1.1
Please advise.

If you look at the mentioned file (node_modules/@types/fs-extra/index.d.ts), you can see that the fs namespace is a NodeJS type, which in turn comes from the @types/node dependency.
Update your @types/node dependency. It works with 16.18.97.
